# NLS_LANG setting on SQLPLUS

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to set NLS_LANG setting to POLISH_POLAND.EE8PC852 in a batch file. The batch file further executes sql files as under

```
set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8PC852
sqlplus username/password@sid @SetLang.sql
```

SetLang.sql updates some tables in my database. When I call this bat file the special characters do not get updated in my database but when I execute the same sql from sqldeveloper they get updated.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks alright to me. Can you execute `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;` within "SetLang.sql" and look what your session parameters are?

The NLS_LANG value in the environment takes precedence over the value in the registry, so that should not be an issue. You may try to change the values in the registry as well, but beware of side effects for other programs.

Also, make sure your SQL Developer NLS settings are set to POLISH_POLAND.EE8PC852 as well.